# Is it possible to send an encrypted message from unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

Is it possible to send an encrypted message from unificationengine?

I have added a connector to my app.

How to send an encrypted  message from unificationengine to my social media?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to send an encrypted message.

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/send  --data "{ \"message\": { \"receivers\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"address\": \"RECEIVER_ADDRESS\" , \"Connector\": \"CONNECTOR_NAME\", \"uri\":\"zalo://ENCRYPTED_URI@zalo.com\"}],\"subject\":\"\",\"parts\": [{\"id\": \"4\",\"contentType\": \"text/plain\", \"data\":\"ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE_CONETENT\" ,\"size\": MESSAGE_SIZE,\"type\": \"body\",\"sort\":0}]}}" -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRETc -k

ENCRYPTED_URI = encrypted uri (CONNECTOR_SCHEME://ACCESS_TOKEN:ACCESS_SECRET@CONNECTOR_SCHEME.com) using openpgp.

ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE_CONETENT = encrypted message data using openpgp